# Error "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04054" JDBC-ORACLE

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g, rdbms

My code looks as follows:

```
ResulSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select passwd from mrs_user where email="+mail_id);
String usr_paswd = rs.getString(1);
```

But the error is as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04054: database link G.COM does not exist
```

> mail_id=dk@g.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, String should be between to quotes `'mail_id'`, but this way is not secure it can cause SQL Injection or syntax error instead you can use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Second, you still not get any result, you have to call `rs.next()` before to moves the cursor to the next row (read about [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)).

---

**Code example**

```
String usr_paswd = null;
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "select passwd from mrs_user where email=?")) {
    stmt.setString(1, mail_id);
    ResulSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
       usr_paswd = rs.getString(1);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It says,
java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

     mrs_user database schema is,

    name,mobile,email,passwd

Comment: @theavatar try to use `if(rs.next()){
           usr_paswd = rs.getString(1);      
        }` maybe there are no result in your table!

Comment: i did but apparently votes cast by people with rep < 15 won't reflect :/